# Как притормозить выполнение основного кода до завершения работы функции?

Tags: javascript, html

В цыкле постоянно меняется переменная которая используется в функции. Перед каждым вызовом функции эта переменная меняется. Дело в том что количество вызовов функции столько сколько переменная менялась . А вот в функции переменная которая менялась 7 раз используется последнее 7 значение этой переменной. Буд то функция запускается только после того как пройдет основной цыкл и потом функция по количеству ее вызовов в этом цыкле начинает выполнение но с уже только последней 7 переменной. Как запускать функцию только после одной смены значения переменной?

```js
(function($){
  function ajaxStart(){
  $('#progress').show();
  }
  function ajaxStop(){
  $('#progress').hide();
  }
 function parserGo(){
  ajaxStart();
  //alert('Started');
  var site=$('input#inputSite').val();
  var b = $.ajax('https://www.google.ru/search?q= '+Mask+'   '+site);

  b.done(function (d) {

  analysisSite(d);
  ajaxStop();
  });
  b.fail(function (e, g, f) {
  alert('Страница недоступна');
  ajaxStop();
  })
  }
  var Mask="";
  $(function(){  
    Mask='testname'; 
    if (Mask.indexOf(('nbsp;'))==-1){
      setTimeout(parserGo(),10000);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

это вырванное из контекста, но мне кажется увидеть проблему можно
переменная Mask берется как глобальная и используется внутри функции analysisSite(), а меняется перед вызовом родительской функции parserGo(). Так вот если представить все возможные значения которые принимает маска(Mask) то в массиве это выглядело бы так Mask[0]='слово1',Mask[1]='слово2'.... и.т.д А у меня после первого вызова parserGo() используется Mask[6]='слово7'. И вызывается эта функиция 7 раз с обной и той же маской.

Comment: код пожалуйста, и обясните, что вам нужно, исходя из кода

Comment: Вырвал из контекста, так как там еще много лишнего. Проблему надеюсь можно понять.

Comment: @Михаил как я понял у вас `ajaxStart()` и `ajaxStop()` функции должны сработать после окончания `ajax` запроса?

Comment: Это просто отображение и скрытие иконки загрузки, ничего особенного.Ну по сути это так, работает с ажаксом так же как и называются.

Comment: @ Jurij Jazdanov, дописал по подробней.

Comment: @Grundy, скажие пожалст, какой вопрос дублирует мой вопрос?

Comment: ссылка указана на плашке, добавил вторую ссылку в дубликат.

Comment: Просмотрев ответы, в тех в которых разобрался, помог только Let, но не до конца. Он только позволил прочитать в функции значение переменной, которую я записал в не цыкла в самом начале программы. И каждый раз при вызове функции читает только это значение.

Comment: еще дополнительно у тебя ошибка в строке `setTimeout(parserGo(),10000);`

Comment: @Grundy, это написано для того чтобы остановить код, но как я понял это наоборот задерживает саму функцию. Сейчас использую просто parserGo().

Comment: @Михаил, ты не прав, это работает не так как ты ожидаешь,  в твоем случае разницы между `setTimeout(parserGo(),10000);` и `parserGo()` нет.

Comment: @Михаил, да я про них, так как в примере они у тебя все-таки стоят

Comment: @Grundy, оу... случайно удалил коммент. Ну в примере они стоят потому что settimout без них не работал почемут... но это уже не важно. Я подобрался близко к решению  своей проблемы. Теперь у меня проблема в запуске функции внутри fikeReader.

Comment: var newvar = new function(x) {return parserGo(x)}(Mask) newvar(); здесь newvar() ругается что не может быть запущена внутри риадера. Но 1 раз она всеже выполняется...

Comment: а ты знаешь что делает оператор `new`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59897/discussion-between-grundy-and-).